# org.hibernate.HibernateException: save is not valid without active transaction

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, persistence

I am creating `JSF` application and using some hibernate stuff in it. All I want to do is to save the entity into the database but I keep getting this exception:

```
org.hibernate.HibernateException: save is not valid without active transaction
```

At first I was getting this exception:

```
org.hibernate.HibernateException: No CurrentSessionContext configured!
```

Then I found that I need to add this into my hibernate configuration:

```
<property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>
```

This solved this issue but now the above one appears.
I am saving entity into database like this:

```
public void create(T entity) {
    getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().save(entity);
}
```

My hibernate.cfg.xml file looks like this:

```
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/online_tests_management</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">root</property>
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
        <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>

        <mapping class="com.groupgti.onlinetests.management.db.Service"/>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

I am using:

- Hibernate-4.1.4.Final
- JDK 1.6
- Tomcat 6
- JSF 2.0
- PrimeFaces 3.3.1
- MySql

Does someone know where might be the problem?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You have to call `session.beginTransaction()`

```
public void create(T entity) {
   Session session=getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
   Transaction trans=session.beginTransaction();
   session.save(entity);
   trans.commit();
}
```

Comment: I am using spring HibernateTransactionManager through Spring AOP to configure transactions. I can see in logs that transaction is starting properly but my save is still failing because I am not using above code. Why is that?

Answer (score 4):

Do it like this:

```
  public void create(T entity) {
       org.hibernate.Session ss= getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
       Transaction tx=ss.beginTransaction();
       ss.save(entity);
       tx.commit();    
  }
```

Do the exception handling part yourself.

Answer (score 3):

Try changing your method to be as follows:

```
public void create(T entity) {
    getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().beginTransaction();
    getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().save(entity);
    getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().endTransaction();
}
```

Should solve your problem.

Answer (score 2):

I think you'll find something like this is more robust and appropriate:

```
Session session = factory.openSession();
Transaction tx = null;
try {
   tx = session.beginTransaction();

   // Do some work like:
   //session.load(...);
   //session.persist(...);
   //session.save(...);

   tx.commit(); // Flush happens automatically
}
catch (RuntimeException e) {
   tx.rollback();
   throw e; // or display error message
}
finally {
    session.close();
}
```

You cannot "close" the transaction, you can close the session, as you can see. Read [this here](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/SessionsAndTransactions), it might be useful for you.

Comment: Care, "openSession" should be avoided. Proper method is "getCurrentSession".